# Get the unique records from scheduled matches in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table like:

| Team1 | Team2 |
| --- | --- |
| CSK | SRH |
| SRH | CSK |
| MI | RR |
| RR | MI |
| DC | MI |

I want to get unique records like below using MSSQL server:

| Team1 | Team2 |
| --- | --- |
| CSK | SRH |
| RR | MI |
| DC | MI |

Comment: without showing your attempt, you are basically asking for someone to do your work for you.

Comment: I tried in my way to get the solution but not happened @MitchWheat

Comment: As a matter of interest why do you want RR MI (as opposed to MI RR), whereas you take CSK SRH instead of SRH CSK.  There doesn't appear to be any rule behind this.

Comment: Yes, the order of the team's name is not a problem but we need to get the unique records of scheduled matches.@JonathanWillcock

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If the order is not important you can simply arrange the two teams alphabetically and then do a `SELECT DISTINCT`. Like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
CASE WHEN team1 < team2 THEN team1 ELSE team2 END AS team1,
CASE WHEN team1 < team2 THEN team2 ELSE team1 END AS team2
FROM teams;
```

As it's Monday morning and you are a newbie, I am being kind to you.  Please note for future reference, however, when posting a question here, you are expected to show more effort yourself.

When asking a question involving SQL, it helps enormously to include in your question `CREATE` statements for the tables involved together with `INSERT` statements to enter your sample data.

And then ***always*** show what you have attempted yourself, no matter how embarassing.  Everyone makes mistakes at first.  Some of us 30 years later are still making mistakes.  The best way to learn is to get help fixing your mistakes, but if we cannot see, what you have tried, it makes it harder to know at what level to pitch the answer.